# a error occurs when using boost::bind to the basic listener.cpp

Tags: ros, callback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I made a mistake in previous question [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/262522/a-error-occurs-when-using-boostbind-to-the-basic-listenercpp/). Hence, I closed it. Here is my new question...

I am using boost bind to subscribe to several topics, following [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/63991/how-to-make-callback-function-called-by-several-subscriber/).

I programmed a basic listener.cpp according to the wiki, and added boost::bind to it. Unfornately, the errors occured.

Can anyone help me? Many thanks.

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"

#include <boost/bind.hpp>

void chatterCallback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg) {
    ROS_INFO("I heard: [%s]", msg->data.c_str());
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ros::init(argc, argv, "listener");

    int i = 0;
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("chatter0", 1000, boost::bind(chatterCallback, _1, i));

    ros::spin();

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the compiling result.

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/bind.hpp:22:0,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/publisher.h:35,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:32,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45,
                 from /home/alex/Documents/Tutorials/ROS/wiki/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/listener_bind.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp: In instantiation of ‘struct boost::_bi::result_traits<boost::_bi::unspecified, void (*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const std_msgs::String_<std::allocator<void> > >&)>’:
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind_template.hpp:15:48:   required from ‘class boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, void (*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const std_msgs::String_<std::allocator<void> > >&), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::_bi::value<int> > >’
/home/alex/Documents/Tutorials/ROS/wiki/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/listener_bind.cpp:15:91:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:69:37: error: ‘void (*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const std_msgs::String_<std::allocator<void> > >&)’ is not a class, struct, or union type
     typedef typename F::result_type type;
                                     ^
/home/alex/Documents/Tutorials/ROS/wiki/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/listener_bind.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
/home/alex/Documents/Tutorials/ROS/wiki/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/listener_bind.cpp:15:92: error: no matching function for call to ‘ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const char [9], int, boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, void (*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const std_msgs::String_<std::allocator<void> > >&), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::_bi::value<int> > >)’
     ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("chatter0", 1000, boost::bind(chatterCallback, _1, i));
                                                                                            ^
/home/alex/Documents/Tutorials/ROS/wiki/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/listener_bind.cpp:15:92: note: candidates are:
In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
                 from /home/alex/Documents/Tutorials/ROS/wiki/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/listener_bind.cpp:1:
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:401:14: note: template<class M, class T> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, void (T::*)(M), T*, const ros::TransportHints&)
   Subscriber subscribe(const std::string& topic, uint32_t queue_size, void(T::*fp)(M), T* obj, 
              ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:401:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/alex/Documents/Tutorials/ROS/wiki/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/listener_bind.cpp:15:92: note:   mismatched types ‘void (T::*)(M)’ and ‘boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, void (*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const std_msgs::String_<std::allocator<void> > >&), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::_bi::value<int> > >’
     ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("chatter0", 1000, boost::bind(chatterCallback, _1, i));
                                                                                            ^
In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
                 from /home/alex/Documents/Tutorials/ROS/wiki/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/listener_bind.cpp:1:
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:412:14: note: template<class M, class T> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, void (T::*)(M)const, T*, const ros::TransportHints&)
   Subscriber subscribe(const std::string& topic, uint32_t queue_size, void(T::*fp)(M) const, T* obj, 
              ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:412:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/alex/Documents/Tutorials/ROS/wiki/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/listener_bind.cpp:15:92: note:   mismatched types ‘void (T::*)(M)const’ and ‘boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, void (*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const std_msgs::String_<std::allocator<void> > >&), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::_bi::value<int> > >’
     ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("chatter0", 1000, boost::bind(chatterCallback, _1, i));
                                                                                            ^
In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
                 from /home/alex/Documents/Tutorials/ROS/wiki/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/listener_bind.cpp:1:
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:464:14: note: template<class M, class T> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, void (T::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const M>&), T*, const ros::TransportHints&)
   Subscriber subscribe(const std::string& topic, uint32_t queue_size, 
              ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:464:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/alex/Documents/Tutorials/ROS/wiki/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/listener_bind.cpp:15:92: note:   mismatched types ‘void (T::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const M>&)’ and ‘boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, void (*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const std_msgs::String_<std::allocator<void> > >&), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::_bi::value<int> > >’
     ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("chatter0", 1000, boost::bind(chatterCallback, _1, i));
                                                                                            ^
In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
                 from /home/alex/Documents/Tutorials/ROS/wiki/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/listener_bind.cpp:1:
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:474:14: note: template<class M, class T> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, void (T::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const M>&)const, T*, const ros::TransportHints&)
   Subscriber subscribe(const std::string& topic, uint32_t queue_size, 
              ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:474:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/alex/Documents/Tutorials/ROS/wiki/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/listener_bind.cpp:15:92: note:   mismatched types ‘void (T::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const M>&)const’ and ‘boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, void (*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const std_msgs::String_<std::allocator<void> > >&), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::_bi::value<int> > >’
     ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("chatter0", 1000, boost::bind(chatterCallback, _1, i));
                                                                                            ^
In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
                 from /home/alex/Documents/Tutorials/ROS/wiki/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/listener_bind.cpp:1:
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:528:14: note: template<class M, class T> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, void (T::*)(M), const boost::shared_ptr<U>&, const ros::TransportHints&)
   Subscriber subscribe(const std::string& topic, uint32_t queue_size, void(T::*fp)(M), 
              ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:528:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/alex/Documents/Tutorials/ROS/wiki/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/listener_bind.cpp:15:92: note:   mismatched types ‘void (T::*)(M)’ and ‘boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, void (*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const std_msgs::String_<std::allocator<void> > >&), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::_bi::value<int> > >’
     ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("chatter0", 1000, boost::bind(chatterCallback, _1, i));
                                                                                            ^
In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
                 from /home/alex/Documents/Tutorials/ROS/wiki/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/listener_bind.cpp:1:
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:539:14: note: template<class M, class T> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, void (T::*)(M)const, const boost::shared_ptr<U>&, const ros::TransportHints&)
   Subscriber subscribe(const std::string& topic, uint32_t queue_size, void(T::*fp)(M) const, 
              ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:539:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/alex/Documents/Tutorials/ROS/wiki/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/listener_bind.cpp:15:92: note:   mismatched types ‘void (T::*)(M)const’ and ‘boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, void (*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const std_msgs::String_<std::allocator<void> > >&), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::_bi::value<int> > >’
     ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("chatter0", 1000, boost::bind(chatterCallback, _1, i));
                                                                                            ^
In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
                 from /home/alex/Documents/Tutorials/ROS/wiki/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/listener_bind.cpp:1:
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:593:14: note: template<class M, class T> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, void (T::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const M>&), const boost::shared_ptr<U>&, const ros::TransportHints&)
   Subscriber subscribe(const std::string& topic, uint32_t queue_size, 
              ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:593:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/alex/Documents/Tutorials/ROS/wiki/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/listener_bind.cpp:15:92: note:   mismatched types ‘void (T::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const M>&)’ and ‘boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, void (*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const std_msgs::String_<std::allocator<void> > >&), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::_bi::value<int> > >’
     ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("chatter0", 1000, boost::bind(chatterCallback, _1, i));
                                                                                            ^
In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
                 from /home/alex/Documents/Tutorials/ROS/wiki/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/listener_bind.cpp:1:
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:604:14: note: template<class M, class T> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, void (T::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const M>&)const, const boost::shared_ptr<U>&, const ros::TransportHints&)
   Subscriber subscribe(const std::string& topic, uint32_t queue_size, 
              ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:604:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/alex/Documents/Tutorials/ROS/wiki/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/listener_bind.cpp:15:92: note:   mismatched types ‘void (T::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const M>&)const’ and ‘boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, void (*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const std_msgs::String_<std::allocator<void> > >&), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::_bi::value<int> > >’
     ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("chatter0", 1000, boost::bind(chatterCallback, _1, i));
                                                                                            ^
In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
                 from /home/alex/Documents/Tutorials/ROS/wiki/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/listener_bind.cpp:1:
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:655:14: note: template<class M> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, void (*)(M), const ros::TransportHints&)
   Subscriber subscribe(const std::string& topic, uint32_t queue_size, void(*fp)(M), const TransportHints& transport_hints = TransportHints())
              ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:655:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/alex/Documents/Tutorials/ROS/wiki/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/listener_bind.cpp:15:92: note:   mismatched types ‘void (*)(M)’ and ‘boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, void (*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const std_msgs::String_<std::allocator<void> > >&), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::_bi::value<int> > >’
     ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("chatter0", 1000, boost::bind(chatterCallback, _1, i));
                                                                                            ^
In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
                 from /home/alex/Documents/Tutorials/ROS/wiki/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/listener_bind.cpp:1:
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:703:14: note: template<class M> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, void (*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const M>&), const ros::TransportHints&)
   Subscriber subscribe(const std::string& topic, uint32_t queue_size, void(*fp)(const boost::shared_ptr<M const>&), const TransportHints& transport_hints = TransportHints())
              ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:703:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/alex/Documents/Tutorials/ROS/wiki/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/listener_bind.cpp:15:92: note:   mismatched types ‘void (*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const M>&)’ and ‘boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, void (*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const std_msgs::String_<std::allocator<void> > >&), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::_bi::value<int> > >’
     ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("chatter0", 1000, boost::bind(chatterCallback, _1, i));
                                                                                            ^
In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
                 from /home/alex/Documents/Tutorials/ROS/wiki/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/listener_bind.cpp:1:
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:749:14: note: template<class M> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, const boost::function<void(const boost::shared_ptr<const M>&)>&, const VoidConstPtr&, const ros::TransportHints&)
   Subscriber subscribe(const std::string& topic, uint32_t queue_size, const boost::function<void (const boost::shared_ptr<M const>&)>& callback,
              ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:749:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/alex/Documents/Tutorials/ROS/wiki/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/listener_bind.cpp:15:92: note:   ‘boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, void (*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const std_msgs::String_<std::allocator<void> > >&), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::_bi::value<int> > >’ is not derived from ‘const boost::function<void(const boost::shared_ptr<const M>&)>’
     ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("chatter0", 1000, boost::bind(chatterCallback, _1, i));
                                                                                            ^
In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
                 from /home/alex/Documents/Tutorials/ROS/wiki/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/listener_bind.cpp:1:
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:798:14: note: template<class M, class C> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, const boost::function<void(C)>&, const VoidConstPtr&, const ros::TransportHints&)
   Subscriber subscribe(const std::string& topic, uint32_t queue_size, const boost::function<void (C)>& callback,
              ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:798:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/alex/Documents/Tutorials/ROS/wiki/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/listener_bind.cpp:15:92: note:   ‘boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, void (*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const std_msgs::String_<std::allocator<void> > >&), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::_bi::value<int> > >’ is not derived from ‘const boost::function<void(C)>’
     ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("chatter0", 1000, boost::bind(chatterCallback, _1, i));
                                                                                            ^
In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
                 from /home/alex/Documents/Tutorials/ROS/wiki/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/listener_bind.cpp:1:
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:835:14: note: ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(ros::SubscribeOptions&)
   Subscriber subscribe(SubscribeOptions& ops);
              ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:835:14: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 3 provided
make[2]: *** [beginner_tutorials/CMakeFiles/listener_bind.dir/src/listener_bind.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [beginner_tutorials/CMakeFiles/listener_bind.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j8 -l8" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262581/a-error-occurs-when-using-boost::bind-to-the-basic-listener.cpp/) by [Xiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/12726/xiang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2017-05-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The issued is solved by add the type to subscribe(). Also, do not forget to add 'int i' to the assignment of callback().

```
void chatterCallback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg, int i) {
    ROS_INFO("I heard: [%s]", msg->data.c_str());
}
```

In main():

```
ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe<std_msgs::String>("chatter0", 1000, boost::bind(chatterCallback, _1, i));
```

---

Originally posted by [Xiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/12726/xiang/) with karma: 46 on 2017-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1